# Jackson ignores Annotations during serialization

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following structure to serialize

```
@JsonTypeName("DS")
public class Elemencik implements IC {

    private String item;

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Elemencik() {
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Elemencik.class)
})
public interface IC {
}
```

I use ObjectMapper to serialize instance of Elemencik class.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);
IC mm = new Elemencik();
String res = mapper.writeValueAsString(mm);
```

After serialization I see that mapper ingores information about type included in annotation @JsonTypeName("DS"). So final json does not have field type.
This is my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem in your `import` if your import is

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;
```

then it can't serialize type field and you have this string:

```
{"item":null}
```

but if your import is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

and the code is:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);
IC mm = new Elemencik();
String res = mapper.writeValueAsString(mm);
```

it can serialize type field and you have the following string:

```
{"type":"DS","item":null}
```